# Making a help section with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javahelp

I want to make a help section for my JavaFX program. I know for Swing there is JavaHelp, which allows you to design your help system using HTML files and it generates an index, table of contents and a search system.

I have been searching but couldn't find anything similar for JavaFX.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: If you already have the HTML files just create a new Stage with a WebView and load the HTML files. You can create all the functionalities like search etc through HTML and navigate from there. You could load the html from resources but i suggest to have them locally saved somewhere probably into the programs main directory, At least that's how i would do it.

Comment: You can actually find a lot of free templates on the web which you can use and change them in a way you like to display your HTML files.